# error connecting to server while fetching JSON data in Fragment

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments, httpclient

I am trying to fetch JSON data from the php file with the code below in my fragment but every time I run the code, the system always returns the Toast called when `result=false` indicating that no data was fetched. What could be the issue causing the data fetch failure?

Here is the code for the inded.php file containing the JSON data.

```
<?php
$arr = array ( "properties"    =>   array(
            array(
                "companyName"   =>  "Motorola",
                "name" => "Moto"
            ),
            array(
                "companyName" => "Sony",
                "name" => "xPeria"
            ),
            array(
                "companyName" => "Infinix",
                "name" => "S2 Pro"
            )
        )
);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Below is the code in the `onCreateView()` section of the fragment.

```
    new JSONAsynTask().execute("http://buvick-group.com/app/index.php");
```

Below is the code for my `JSONAsynTask()` class.

```
class JSONAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    String result;
    ProgressDialog dialog;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {


        try {


            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            Log.e(TAG, "HTTP Internet Result: " + String.valueOf(status));
            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("properties");

                Log.e(TAG, "JSON Result Length: " + String.valueOf(jarray.length()));

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Property property = new Property();

                    property.setName(object.getString("companyName"));
                    property.setDescription(object.getString("name"));

                    propertiesList.add(property);
                }
                return true;
            }
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        dialog.dismiss();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if(result == false)
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you check and tell the status you are getting?

Comment: If you are calling above url then you are parsing it wrong as it doesn't have any JsonArray.

Comment: @UmangBurman am getting status 200. I have modified my code as above

Comment: @Biko Why are you using this: `JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("properties");` There is no such thing called properties in the response

Comment: @UmangBurman I have modified the JSON data. Kindly check now in the question

Comment: Okay, are you getting any data in jArray length()? @Biko

Comment: I have added a log after this line `JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("properties");` (check the code) to display the length of the array but nothing is being displayed in the logcat. Its like the piece of code does not exist...and I am guessing its everything in the if block

Comment: Your php code gives me `false` when I test it online. @Biko

Comment: Thank you @UmangBurman...the problem was in the jSon data. I have modified the php code. The data was not in the proper format. Cheers

Comment: Aye.. Happy to help. Are you getting the output now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a lot of help from @UmangBurman, I was able to get to the bottom of my problem. The issue was the JSON data. With the JSON data format and the correct `JSONAsynTask`, I Hope this question will help someone in the future form a base in their code. I have updated the code in the question to present the debugged version. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling `https://androidtutorialpoint.com/api/MobileJSONObject.json` API then directly parse from JsonObject.

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(data);
Property property = new Property();
property.setName(object.getString("companyName"));
property.setDescription(object.getString("name"));

propertiesList.add(property);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON needs to be redesigned. Here is the code to generate the right json for your android json parsing code

```
<?php
$response = array();
$response["code"] = 200;
$response["properties"] = array();

for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $item = array();
    $item["companyName"] = "Company ".$i;
    $item["name"] = "Model ".$i;
    array_push($response["properties"],  $item );

}


echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

This will print

```
{
"code":200,
"properties":[
{
"companyName":"Company 0",
"name":"Model 0"
},
{
"companyName":"Company 1",
"name":"Model 1"
},
{
"companyName":"Company 2",
"name":"Model 2"
},
{
"companyName":"Company 3",
"name":"Model 3"
},
{
"companyName":"Company 4",
"name":"Model 4"
},
{
"companyName":"Company 5",
"name":"Model 5"
}
]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to run code after deleting last statement **return false** after Try Catch block of your **doInBackground** method. 
It always returns false.
Also add ** return false** in ELSE block..
So your code look like as below, try again

```
class JSONAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    String result;
    ProgressDialog dialog;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {


        try {


            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("properties");

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Property property = new Property();

                    property.setName(object.getString("companyName"));
                    property.setDescription(object.getString("name"));

                    propertiesList.add(property);
                }
                return true;
            }else{

                return false;
             }



        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        dialog.dismiss();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if(result == false)
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: No. if status is 200 it will return true. See his code

Comment: @ShreyaPrajapati Boolean at the end of the return type is definitely required there, hence your code will ask for a return type after try/catch.

Comment: @UmangBurman I hv already added, check my updated code, need to add return statement in else block too.

Comment: @ShreyaPrajapati I meant to say that a return is required after the last catch() .. You've not added at the end but in if condition.

Comment: Okay, I see it now, But does it answer the OP.?

Comment: I have tried this code snippet but the error still remains. The **HTTP status code is 200** so I really do not understand the problem